# Demystify ssh tunneling into Marathon master and agents

Tags: ssh, marathon, dcos

We're running DC/OS + Marathon on an Azure cluster (ACS). I find myself in situations where it would be very helpful to tunnel into the master node and more specifically - agent nodes. Then I'd like to run bash commands against my services (docker images) that are running. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's a page on ACS's documentation regarding ssh tunneling into master nodes, it can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/container-service-connect/

Say you have an Azure Container Service named my-acs running on the East US region, and your user name is myuser, and you would like to access the DC/OS dashboard of your cluster,

```
sudo ssh -L 80:localhost:80 -f -N my-user@my-acsmgmt.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -i path/to/your/private/key
```

If you would like to directly access the terminal of your master, you would use:

```
ssh my-user@my-acsmgmt.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -i path/to/your/private/key
```

However, I do not know how to connect directly into an Agent node.

Comment: The easiest way to connect to the agents is via a tunnel to the masters. Use '-A' in the SSH connection and your credentials will be forwarded and thus you can simply 'ssh AGENT_IP`.

Comment: Ross, I've ssh with -A from the master into an agent node and got this:

`ssh: /opt/mesosphere/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)

ssh: /opt/mesosphere/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)

The authenticity of host '10.32.0.6 (10.32.0.6)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is REDACTED.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added '10.32.0.6' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Also tried with -A from my host to the master and then into the agent, also permission denied. Is there anything wrong with my DC/OS masters? Running a cluster with 3 masters right now, wasn't able to do that from any of them

Comment: You need to ensure you have setup SSH correctly to forward your keys. See http://unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html for a good guide on the topic.